# PHP and javascript POST

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">


 function displayTweet(){
var i = 0;
var limit = $("#twitter-results > div").size();
var myInterval = window.setInterval(function () {
var element = $("#twitter-results div:last-child");
$("#twitter-results").prepend(element);
element.fadeIn("slow");
i++;
if(i==limit){
window.setTimeout(function () {
clearInterval(myInterval);
});
}
},2000);
}

$("form#twittersearch").submit(function() {
twitterq = $('#twitterq').attr('value');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "search.php",
cache: false,
data: "twitterq="+ twitterq,
success: function(html){
$("#twitter-results").html(html);
displayTweet();
}
});
return false;
});
});

</script>

</head>
<div class="twitter_container">
<form id="twittersearch" method="post" action="">
<input name="twitterq" type="text" id="twitterq" />
<button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<div id="twitter-results"></div>
</div>
</html>


/***************THIS IS search.php***************************/

<?php
include('twitterapi.php');
if($_POST['twitterq']){
$twitter_query = $_POST['twitterq'];
$search = new TwitterSearch($twitter_query);
$results = $search->results();

foreach($results as $result){
    echo '<div class="twitter_status">';
    echo '<img src="'.$result->profile_image_url.'" class="twitter_image">';
    $text_n = toLink($result->text);
    echo $text_n;
    echo '<div class="twitter_small">';
    echo '<strong>From:</strong> <a href="http://www.twitter.com/'.$result->from_user.'">'.$result->from_user.'</a&glt;: ';
    echo '<strong>at:</strong> '.$result->created_at;
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
}
?>
```

Why is it that when I do a `var_dump($_POST['twitterq'])` it is always NULL?

**UPDATE:**

firebug gave me this, not sure how to fix it though:

[image]

[image]

Comment: and value of twitterq in JS? correct?

Comment: I don't think doing it like `"twitterq="+ twitterq,` that will work. Have you tried `data : {'twitterq' : twitterq}` ?

Comment: tried that, doesn't work

Comment: I did try alert(twitterq) and it prints out the value in the search

Comment: try to post without ajax, and make sure that works. and since in do not have twitterapi.php i cannot test.

Comment: updated my post above from firebug

Comment: well, `Response` or `HTML` please

Comment: well actually it did go into that _$POST if statement, question now is why doesn't it give back anything

Comment: it doesn't give you anything because, you have an error, `Internal server error`. Just click on `Response` or `HTML` to view this error and try by removing this ajax (without using ajax) and see what exactly error you get (fix it and use ajax).

Comment: if I remove the ajax there is no error... I can see why it's not displaying, because it is not a success and it didn't call the displayTweet

Comment: can you post your twitterapi.php file

Comment: figured out the error, it's at my search.php.. when it tries to call $text_n = toLink($result->text); it breaks down, I am assuming that twitterapi.php doesn't have this function.. I am just copying the twitterapi.php from http://greenservr.com/projects/twittersearch/TwitterSearch.phps

Comment: can someone help me to find the correct twitterapi.php that is used in that tutorial? the download link is broken and I assume the one that I find is not the correct version

Comment: what is that toLink method anyway?

Comment: i will check the code and if, i figure it out, i will post the answer.

Comment: just remove that `toLink` function, and `echo $result->text` that should work.

Comment: kind of an off topic question, the tutorial says that "you can modify to get a real-time stream of messages for example calling a new ajax request (to search.php) every time the current array with the search results is totally displayed in the page". How do I check this?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not providing the data properly. It should be:

```
data: ({twitterq: twitterq}),
```

You are sending data in the form of JSON. You are not using URL parameters , so there is no need of '='. if you have more than one parameters, you will simply separate them with commas.

Comment: I am just following the tutorial here http://www.webspeaks.in/2010/03/twitter-api-how-to-create-stream-of.html

Comment: check in firebug if any value is POSTed onto the server thru ur ajax

Comment: well, i am not worried about who.. i am want to know why. whoever voted should have explained the mistake!

Comment: well, don't have idea. i will vote you up to cancel the downvote then. But to be honest, i don't see it responds the problem in question properly. But also for your info `"twitterq="+ twitterq` works fine